# Error in building new package in rosjava_core

Tags: ros, rosjava-core, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to build a new `rosjava_core` package and follow the same step as given [here](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-java-package). I used `build.gradle` as given in tutorial and on using both commands `gradle build` and `gradle installApp` I get error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'test_java_core'.
Cause: Could not find method maven() for arguments [build_qrpk3gb7vg4fn9nn26dq7oqkj$_run_closure1_closure3@11eea7f0] on root project 'test_java_core'.
```

Then I copied build.gradle from rosjava_tutorial_pubsub to my new package. I got error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'test_java_core'.
Cause: Project with path ':rosjava' could not be found in root project 'test_java_core'.
```

Did some one have same problem? Any hints about the solution?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46961/error-in-building-new-package-in-rosjava_core/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-10-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first problem is that the gradle version you're using (probably the one from the Ubuntu repos, installed via `apt-get`) is too old for rosjava. You can find out which version you're using by running

```
gradle -v
```

- throws the error you mentioned (Oneiric version): `Gradle 1.0-milestone-3`
- works (rosjava version): `Gradle 1.0-milestone-9`

You have two options. Either you manually install the newest gradle from the web site, or you use the gradle version bundled with rosjava like this:

```
mkdir ~/bin
ln -s ros/stacks/rosjava_core/gradlew ~/bin/gradle    # or wherever you installed rosjava_core
echo 'export PATH=~/bin:$PATH' >> .bashrc
source .bashrc
```

---

As for your second problem, don't copy the `build.gradle` file from `rosjava_tutorial_pubsub`, because it won't work outside the `rosjava_core` directory (it's meant to be built as a subproject of rosjava). Instead, use the `build.gradle` file from the rosjava "Getting Started" page you linked to.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-10-30**:
First issue reported here: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=149

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-10-30**:
Now it compiles. but gives error: my_workspace/test_java_core/src/main/java/org/ros/test_java_core/Listener.java:28: GraphName(java.lang.String) has private access in org.ros.namespace.GraphName
return new GraphName("test_java_core/listener"); I took listener and talker from pubsub tutorial.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-10-30**:
Again, that's a different problem, so please open a new question for that. And since my answer solved your problem, please mark it as correct. Thank you.

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-10-30**:
ok, thanks...it compiles and has successfully used the gradle bundled with rosjava. Can you please now answer the query on http://answers.ros.org/question/47142/graphname-private-access-error-in-rosjava_core/

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-10-30**:
Do you even read my comments?

> And since my answer solved your problem, please mark it as correct. Thank you.

These rules are there to indicate to other people looking for an answer, or willing to provide an answer, that this problem is solved (and what the solution was), so please abide to them.

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-10-31**:
hi hi yes I have marked it as correct by clicking on good sybmol under the answer number on left uper side . I did not know this before. thanks..its done now :-).